# I'm getting hidden symbol `curl_easy_setopt' in ../curl/lib/.libs//libcurl.a

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl

I've recently upgraded curl to 7.38 and now trying to build my application on RHEL4 with gcc 4.1.2
I'm getting:
hidden symbol `curl_easy_setopt' in ../curl/lib/.libs//libcurl.a(libcurl_la-easy.o) is referenced by DSO when it tries to link the executable.
the curl library does not seem to have any issues to build. i've built it with zlib and openssl options.
I checked easy.o it's present. Source quick review did not reveal anything suspicious right away. 
any ideas will be greatly appreciated.
G